# Web Resources and Tutorials?

Tags: nft

Does anyone have any reccomendations on tutorials to create token minting websites?  I have learned how to mint nfts to the chain and need to expand my knowledge.  any help appreciated.  thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

This one shoud be a good start

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting/